# How do I include characters, but not allow repeating characters?

Tags: regex

I don't want repeating question marks, but I want to allow multiple question marks anywhere as long as it's not repeated. I couldn't get it to work within the squared brackets.

```
([a-z#$@]+\?{1}[a-z#$@]+)

should?matchthisentirely?abc?abc

should??notwork
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex like this:

```
^(?!.*[?]{2})[a-z#$@?]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9i3vq2/1)

`(?!.*[?]{2})` is negative lookahead, that will disallow multiple `?` anywhere in the input.

---

If you also want to disallow `?` at start and end then you can use this regex with 2 additional negative lookaheads

```
^(?![?])(?!.*[?]$)(?!.*[?]{2})[a-z#$@?]+$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9i3vq2/2)

Here:

- `(?![?])` - don't allow `?` at the start
- `(?!.*[?]$)` - don't allow `?` at the end